# What url structure should I use when retrieving users via a token?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm using Django Rest Framework to handle token authentication for a mobile application for a school. In particular, when a student logs in, the mobile application sends a token to my Django backend, which then combines data from its database and some external data from another source. I found it easiest to use a generic RetrieveAPIView to accomplish what I needed.

My code is working, and my main question is around the url. For most retrievals, we usually have the primary key as well (e.g. /students/SOME-ID), but in this case, I'm using the token to retrieve the user rather than the primary key. In fact, if `SOME-ID` passed in was different from the Token, the user associated with the Token would be returned anyway (which seems kinda strange).

I'm wondering whether it is better to have my url route be just (/students) instead though this seems to be a list rather than a retrieve operation.

WHAT I HAVE NOW

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/revision/students/1
```

IS THIS BETTER

```
http://localhost:8000/api/v1/revision/students/
```

CODE

```
class StudentView(generics.RetrieveAPIView):
    model = Student
    serializer_class = StudentSerializer

    # combines data from both current and legacy database
    def retrieve(self, request, pk=None):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Student, user=request.user)
        # KIV -> unsure if this is the best way to combine data from legacy and current database
        # or should it be done in the serializer
        data = StudentSerializer(obj).data

        # combines existing data stored in database with legacy data from database
        legacy_data = SOME_EXTERNAL_API_SERVICE.get_student_info(obj) 
        data['avatar'] = legacy_data['avatar']
        data['coins'] = legacy_data['coins']
        return Response(data)
```

Comment: How's the token passed? I would have said `/students/<token>` but it looks like you're passing the token in a different way. If ID doesn't matter in the URL, I would use a custom name for this URL: `/students/current` or something similar.

Comment: I'm passing the token via a header (Authorization: Token xxxxx). Oh I like the /students/current/ approach - is this standard practice according to REST?

Comment: Well, your case is a bit of an edge one in REST. Strictly speaking you should pass an `id` if you're fetching a specific resource (but that's not what your API does). And normally, when filtering resources, you'd use query parameters, e.g. `/students/?q=current` but that's a bit ugly in this case where you're just returning one object. Special cases are acceptable, like also special actions that don't fit into CRUD (`/students/id/flag`). The main goal is for the API to be readable and logical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would definitely not use `/students/id/` with the behaviour you're describing: This URL should always return the student with the given `id` of error (depending on whether the user fetching this resource is allowed to do so). You might want to use this URL for admins to view students in the future.

And for the same reason, I wouldn't use `/students/` because I'd expect it to return a list of all students, or at least the list of all students the particular logged in user is allowed to see. This might fit your purpose now (where the logged in user can only see himself), but maybe not in the future if you create new roles that can view more students.

There are two approaches here:

- Either you treat this as a filter on all the students: `/students/?current=true` which I personally find ugly because you're not actually filtering on the total set of students.
- Or you treat this as a special case: `/students/current` using a special keyword for fetching this one specific student.

I would choose the latter one because it is more descriptive and easier to understand when looking at the API. Note of course that `id` can never be 'current' in this case, which is why some people discourage this kind of special resource queries and opt for the first option.

Comment: Thank you, and this is what I eventually ended up doing!

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, the url `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/revision/students/` looks better.

But you don't need to write this in a `RetrieveAPIView`, you could always do this in base `APIView`,

```
class StudentView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        obj = get_object_or_404(Student, user=request.user)
        data = StudentSerializer(obj).data
        legacy_data = SOME_EXTERNAL_API_SERVICE.get_student_info(obj) 
        data['avatar'] = legacy_data['avatar']
        data['coins'] = legacy_data['coins']
        return Response(data)
```

By using like this, you can avoid the extra `pk` keyword argument from your url.